# How do we traverse from nth to last element in a linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

The code below returns the kth to last element of a linked list. But I don't understand how this is, because doesn't 'for I in range(k)' return values from 0 to k?? As opposed to k to the last element?

Also in general, can someone please explain the traversal of the below, as I don't quite understand it- I do understand the fundamentals of linked list and the syntax but can't quite follow the code below. e.g. why is there a need for a runner (I'm assuming this is some sort of pointer?)

```
def kth_to_last(l1,k):
    runner = current = l1.head                            

 for i in range(k):
        if runner is None:
            return None
        runner = runner.next

        while runner:
            current = current.next
            runner = runner.next

    return current
```

e.g. input is a linked list: a -> b -> c-> d-> None
if k is b then
output: b -> c -> d -> None

Comment: Why don't you include a [example] in the question (linked list implementation)?

Comment: And make sure that the code you posted is correct. That will immediately throw indentation error.

Comment: (try running the code with pencil and paper. It isn't that hard to understand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in linked list, each node only knows the next node (some times the previous one too). in that case, you cannot just "jump" k nodes forward. you need to move 1 node forward k times.

in this case, runner is the pointer for the 'current' node.  its often also named "current", but since this one 'runs' over the list and doesn't really care much for its content, they named it "runner".

let say runner holds the rout, i.e. node #0

```
runner = runner.next
```

the node next to node#0 is node#1, so now runner is node#1

```
runner = runner.next
```

and now runner is node#2 and so forth. each iteration of runner = runner.next forward you 1 node.
so in order to move from node#0 to node#27, you need to write runner = runner.next 27 times, or use a loop for it.
(note: the "if" part of the loop is mostly to avoid exceptions, since you cant get the "next" of null)

a simpler way to make\understand this function is by finding the length of the list, decreasing it by k and than moving forward that many nodes.